# Unfortunately myapp has stopped (imagebutton for FB)

Tags: android, facebook

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmdzH.png)
[xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx0SJ.png)
Please help me, when I run the application directly out "unfortunately the application has been stopped". Before the button was changed to ImageButton, its application can run normally.

Comment: Please, post your code here.

Comment: Kindly, do not vandalise your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your referencing of Button in your activity to ImageButton.

I assume:

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Change that to:

```
ImageButton btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: haha thanks, BTW did you know how to build mini chat in android (using eclipse)?

Comment: Try [this out](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiiiYW7-NrLAhWHbhQKHeEEBJAQtwIIKTAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoJgfnXRF8PM&usg=AFQjCNGBmNVKRc7ZgQgAnoWbJUK4k4H_Kw&sig2=6oPtQ25_0606tGEubCch8Q). Using firebase takes care of alot of issues you dont have to worry about.

Comment: @Steave can you help me again? i got a problem when i login to FB. it say "Invalid Scopes: publish_steam. this message is only shown to developers. users of your app will ignore these permision if present. plaese read the documentation for valid permision at /developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permisions"

Comment: Have you added the said permissions you are trying to access, like  `loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));`